# Learn Python the hard way ex43

Tags: python

I'm sorry that this question has been asked, and answered multiple times. I've checked out loads of them, with the exact problem and seen their answers but they either don't work for me or are too jargon heavy for my simple mind to understand. Here's my code ;

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        print("Scene not configured")
        exit(1)

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

class Death(Scene):

    quips = [
    "Your dead",
    "rekt",
    "super rekt"]

    def enter(self):
        print(Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)])
        exit(1)

class Corridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print("\nYou've a gun and stuff, what will you do? Shoot/Leg it")

        action = input("\n>> ")

        if action == "Shoot":
            print("\nYou killed someone, good stuff")
            print("You get into the armory.")
            return 'laser_weapon_armory'

        elif action == "Leg it":
            print("\nYou get shot before you get away.")
            return 'death'

        else:
            print("\nThat was not an option")
            return 'central_corridor'

class LaserWeaponArmory(Scene):

    def enter(Self):
        print("\nRight, you're in the armory.")
        print("There's a lock on the next door. \nEnter 3 digits to unlock")
        code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
        guess = input("\n >> ")
        guesses = 0

        while guess != code and guesses < 10:
            print("\nDENIED")
            guesses += 1
            guess = input("\n >> ")

        if guess == code:
            print("\nDoor opens.")
            print("You enter the bridge.")
            return 'the_bridge'

        else:
            print("\nDoor remains locked. You get killed")
            Death()

class TheBridge(Scene):

    def enter(Self):
        print("\nYou're in the bridge.")
        print("There's a bomb. What do you do?")
        print("Defuse/Run away")

        action = input("\n >> ")

        if action == 'Defuse':
            print("\nYou failed, bomb goes off")
            return 'death'

        elif action == 'Run away':
            print("\nYou get in the escape pod bay.")
            return 'escape_pod'

        else:
            print("\nThat was not an option.")
            Death()

class EscapePod(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print("\nThere's 5 pods, which do you take?")

        good_pod = randint(1.5)
        pod = input("\n>>Pod #")

        if int(pod) != good_pod:
            print("\nThis pod is fucked.")
            Death()

        else:
            print("\nYurt, the pod works. You're out of here kid.")
            return 'finished'

class Finished(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print("\nGame over. Go away.")
        return 'finished'

class Map(object):

    scenes = {
    'central_corridor': Corridor(),
    'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
    'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
    'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
    'finished': Finished(),
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene
        print("start_scene in __init__", self.start_scene)

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

    a_map = Map('central_corridor')
    a_game = Engine(a_map)
    a_game.play()
```

Error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Shtuff\game.py", line 143, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "C:\Python\Shtuff\game.py", line 20, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

I'm very new to Python, mostly understand Classes and all that though. As far as I can see this is exactly like the code in LPTHW. Two of the answers I've seen for this exact problem I have in my code so can't see where I'm going wrong. Could it be something got to do with me using Python3 and LPTHW all about Python 2.XX?

Comment: [Why learn python the hard way when you can learn it easily!](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get` method of a dictionary returns `None` for non-existent keys:

```
a = {'hello': 'world'}

print(a.get('hello')) # -> world
print(a.get('test'))  # -> None
```

You assume that each scene's `enter` method returns the name of the next scene. Some of these methods return `'death'` (see `Corridor` and `TheBridge`, for example). Then this return value is used as a key for `Map.scenes`. But there's no `'death'` key there, so it's returning `None`.

---

By the way, `self` and `Self` are quite different, but you're using both and expecting them to do the same thing.

Comment: Yep, adding in 'death': Death() fixed it, thanks. Didn't mean to have the differences in self/Self either!